# Serving various sites inside one VPS with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, nginx, vps, unicorn

I followed a tutorial in Rails Casts: [#335 Deploying to a VPS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps). I have a linode VPS set up with an Ubuntu 10.04 image and I can deploy to it. Now it's serving:

```
/home/user0/first-rails-app/public (domain1.com)
```

I want to use nginx to serve another rails app and a php app, asume they are stored here:

```
/home/user1/php-app/public (domain2.com)
/home/user2/another-rails-app/public (subdomain.domain1.com)
```

My nginx.conf

```
upstream unicorn {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  # server_name example.com;
  root /home/user0/first-rails-app/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

All the domains and sub domain point to the server (x.x.x.x). I'm not sure how to use unicorn with two rails apps in the same server, even if I get virtual hosts correctly setup in nginx.conf.

Any suggestions where to start looking or what to modify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to declare multiple upstreams in your conf

```
upstream app1 { server unix:/tmp/app1.sock; }
upstream app2 { server unix:/tmp/app2.sock; }

server {
  server_name http://www.example.com
  location /foo {proxy_pass http://app1; break;}
  location /bar {proxy_pass http://app2; break;}
}
```